# Returning a list of column Headers when the row value is zero

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I have several tables in excel similar to the image. Each row is labeled with a student name and the column headers are words they are tested on. The cell values are 1 for a correct answer and zero for incorrect. What I want to do is, in a separate sheet, list the words each student missed. I need a function that will return the column header for each 0 in the row with a given student name. I need a single function that will return every missed word per student.

What I want is a function like: "for('Given student Name, in given table'), list all missed words". 
The output would look something like:

Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4

```
        on    and

        this  on

              the

              this
```

I cant use VBA for this.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried, and what is not working?

Comment: Have you had a look a pivot tables? Countifs?

Comment: I have tried modifying similar functions to this: =IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$8)),ROW(3:3)),2)),"",INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$8)),ROW(3:3)),2)) Taken from http://eimagine.com/how-to-return-multiple-match-values-in-excel-using-index-match-or-vlookup/. I cant seem to modify this function to fit my table. Pivot tables wont return the column headers (Not that I know of anyway). I have also tried using =IF(Row cell=0,'Col header',"") and dragging. This works but leaves gaps in the cells that will make other things I need to do harder.

Answer (score 0):

okay, so this works on my test:

1. Add to the cell above Name1: User
2. Make a pivot of the columns
3. for the PivotTable Fields:In columns put user, in values put SUM OF columns, move "Values" from Columns to Rows
4. See: [image: This for example]
5. Now enter this formula: `=IF(B5=1,"",RIGHT($A5,LEN($A5)-7))` into a free cell, in my example this was `H5`
6. Fill this formula across to make up the grid
7. Profit!!  :D

Comment: Your solution works. I can create the same table without the pivot using a more complicated IF formula.The reason I didn't like that method is the blank cells for each word the student got correct. For example, if a student only missed the last word, only the top cell under his name would be filled with that word.